# Neat method signature to find subclasses of a given type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a method that I have implemented, but am having trouble getting the method signature to be elegant.

The method returns all classes which are a subclass of a specified class. My current method signature looks like :

```
public func allSubclassesOf(baseClass: AnyClass) -> [AnyClass]
```

which is fine, apart from the return type being `AnyClass` which means I always end up with a messy cast like this:

```
allSubClassesOf(UIView).forEach { (subclass:AnyClass) in
    UIView *sigh = subclass as! UIView //!< Gross and unnecessary
    ...
}
```

This seems like something that generics should be able to solve :)

Things I've tried :

```
public func allSubclassesOf<T>() -> [T]
```

Nope, you're not allowed to add generics to a function like that.

```
extension NSObject {
    class func allSubclasses() -> [Self]
}
```

Nope, Self isn't available here.

Does anyone know how I can pass a type into this method and have the compiler know what type the returning array would hold; removing the need for a cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the implementation of your method but you would need to do something like the following.

What I am doing here is applying a generic type to the method function then saying that I would expect the object type as an argument and return instances of the type in an array.

You could add it as an extension, however without more examples for your code I can't help any further

```
func subclasses<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
  ....
}

subclasses(UIView).forEach { (view: UIView) in
  print(view)
}
```

Comment: Nice. The lesson for me was realising I have to define the type of T from a parameter, I can't just specify it when I call the method. Thanks :)

Comment: @deanWombourne Yea you define it in the method signature and it type type will get inferred, once you wrap your head around a few of these it will become easier. generics are hard, keep at it

Comment: I was just surprised that I couldn't do `subclasses<UIView>().forEach { view in ... }` and just specify the type of T directly. I think I'm OKish with Generics, it's Swift that's the learning curve for me :)